# Move r packages to new computer which has no internet

Tags: r, installation

Normally I install packages using:

```
install.packages("foo")
```

and a Repo over the internet. But I have a new machine now where I want to replicate the packages from my existing installation without having to pull everything off the internet all over again. (I've a ton of packages and slow  internet access)

Both machines are Windows and run the same R version. (2.13.1)

Is there a way to do this? Closest I can get is I know I can install from local zip files using:

```
install.packages("pathtozip", repos = NULL)
```

But does R store all Zips somewhere? I found a few in locations like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\foouser\Local Settings\Temp\RtmpjNKkyp\downloaded_packages
```

But not all.

Any tips?

Comment: `copydir.bat` and `movedir.bat` in batchfiles will copy and move libraries respectively. See http://batchfiles.googlecode.com .  See comments at the top of each of these files.

Comment: This was a question already, which I cannot seem to find right now, but I recall @DWin gave a very solid answer to it.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck and RSaporta. Will try.

Comment: Can  "copydir 2.10\library 2.11\library" be used with an intermediate location on a removable drive? Both installations being on different machines are not simultaneously visible.

Comment: Use `.libPaths()` in R to verify where user library is located.  Then its something like this on old machine from Windows cmd line: `copydir.bat "%userprofile%\Documents\R\win-library\2.15" F:\2.15` assuming the USB is `F:`.  On new machine from Windows cmd line:  `set  newdir="%userprofile%\Documents\R\win-library\2.15"` & then `md %newdir%` and then `copydir.bat F:\2.15 %newdir%` .  Main advantage of `copydir.bat` is that it won't overwrite anything but that is not of concern here so you could alternately use the built in `xcopy` or use `robocopy` or use Windows Explorer to do the copying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function `.libPaths` will give you a vector of all the libraries on your machine. Run this on your old machine to find all of them. You can simply copy all these files into the libraries on your new machine (run `.libPaths` on it too to find out where).

Alternatively, if you want to set up a real repository (i.e. basically a CRAN mirror) on your computer or on a network drive you can update, you can put binary or source packages into a folder and run `tools::write_PACKAGES` on that folder. You can them run `install.packages` using the `contriburl` argument and point it to your repository folder.

Comment: After having just gone through this process, the issue you can run into with the 2nd approach (a local CRAN mirror, using `tools::write_PACKAGES` etc.), is that some libraries may be missing (e.g. `stringi` uses the `ICU4C` library, which gets automatically installed when connected to the internet).  This comment is meant as a heads up for folks taking this path.

Comment: I ran into that issue too once. You can download it separately or pre-install it on the machine. In either case, the [install instructions](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/blob/master/INSTALL) from the project page are useful.

Comment: I ended up using the install instructions to build stringi using GitHub. This worked well and handled the ICU4C dependency.

Answer (score 12):

All packages that you have installed are stored in a folder called win-library\r-version, for example, 
C:\Users\Ehsan\Documents\R\win-library\2.15 so, it is enough to copy all the folders inside 2.15 to the same folder in your new machine. because you have the same version of R you do not need to update them by update.packages().

Answer (score -2):

On your **original** computer, run

```
write.csv(unique(data.frame(installed.packages())[,1]),"packages.csv",row.names=F)
```

Save this .csv into the working directory of your **new** computer, then run

```
install.packages(as.character(read.csv("packages.csv")[,1]))
```

You can check what your working directory is using `getwd()`.

Comment: `install.packages` downloads from a repository over the internet and won't work on the new machine, which is not connected to the internet.