# RStudio: Taking over installed packages and basic settings when moving to a new PC

Tags: r, plugins, export, settings

I have to move to a new PC. Old and new OS is Win10.
Now, I would like not to write a list of my installed plugins by hand and then installing them seperately with comparing this list for each, ... . Rather I would prefer to manage this say (half) automatically.

So, I am looking for options to take over those settings.
Are there according settings-files in the user/program-directories, or may I write and import according files?

If yes: How does it work, or where do I find the files, respectively?
If no: Would it be at least possible to print a list of the installed packages by R-code?

And still a subsequent question as I am quite new to RStudio:
Are there other settings/informations you would recommend to be aware of when migrating?

Comment: For packages: you can save `installed.packages()` to a file and read that with an `install.packages` call. I don't use plugins so not sure whether a list exists for those but you can check  `rstudioapi` (I think that's the package's name)

Comment: While less likely these days, you should still look for (and copy, if present) files within your `$HOME` directory: `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron`. (It is not a problem if they do not exist, you do not need to create them.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060956/move-r-packages-to-new-computer-which-has-no-internet  i would check .libPaths() and simply copy the whole folder over to the new machine .