# Copy libraries / Install packages for R to computer with no internet - Win 10

Tags: r, rstudio, libraries

My small employer has recently been acquired by a much larger multi-national which means we've moved from an easy-to-navigate IT environment to what I will politely call a non-permissive one. While R and RStudio are permitted installations, access to the package repositories via the `install.packages()` command is blocked. Very frustrating.

I can copy all of the files and folders for the package libraries (I.E. from `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library` and `C:/Users/AndrewM/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2`) from the old machine to the new machine per this answer [Copy Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061065/5029107) but when trying to use any of those packages via `library(openxlsx)` for example, I get the dreaded

```
Error in library(openxlsx) : there is no package called ‘openxlsx’
```

Does this method no longer work (maybe it never worked)? Is the only path forward to manually download every single package.zip and install in that fashion? This makes installing packages like Tidyverse exceptionally challenging as each package within the Tidyverse requires individual install as well.

Edit: Originally copied the packages from old to new via OneDrive. This proved to be the root cause of the failure. Use of a USB drive to copy the libraries over precisely as originally described was successful.

Comment: Once you have copied to your search path, restart the session

Comment: Make sure the R versions are the same, since (1) the use of appdata was introduced relatively recently, and (2) if the new workstation is on an older minor version (e.g., not `R-4.2`) then they are not (perfectly?) compatible. Also, you might want to verify (just in case?) that `Sys.getenv("APPDATA")` is where you think it is, I can imagine enterprise setups might move things around.

Comment: `.libPaths()` will show where R thinks the libraries are.

Comment: I used '.libPaths()' to get the library locations on both machines so reasonably confident on that. I updated R and RStudio on the old machine, and did fresh installs on the new machine so they too should be in sync.

Comment: @onyambu I even tried rebooting the entire system in addition to restarting R and new sessions. To no avail.

Comment: When you copy to the new machine, where do you place the packages?

Comment: Into the relevant paths spit out by '.libPaths()' on the new computer. That seemed logical but I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: What does `installed.packages()` show on the new machine? That should show everything R can see and where it's located.

Comment: Oh ha! It would seem that my original copying over via OneDrive (installed on both machines) was unsuitable. Getting a temporary USB exception from the IT overlords allowed me to re-copy from the old machine to the new and that solved the problem. 'installed.packages()' now lists all of the expected libraries and 'library()' calls work as expected. Thanks everyone for assistance.